# Extracting every 3rd data in an array

Tags: python, graph, numpy

I have thousand of data for x and y, for this case i will just use 12 data.
The array are used to plot a graph

```
x = np.array([1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000])
y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
py.plot(x,y)
```

How can i extract every [3] multiplication for me to plot? For Example

```
x = np.array([3000,6000,9000,12000])
y = np.array([3,6,9,12])
py.plot(x,y)
```

How can i extract every [5] multiplication for me to plot ? For Example

```
x = np.array([5000,10000])
y = np.array([5,10])
py.plot(x,y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract every third item starting with the third item (one dimensional array)

```
x[2::3], y[2::3]
```

Extract every fifth item starting with the fifth item (one dimensional array)

```
x[4::5], y[4::5]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're just asking how to extract every x-th item, slicing accepts a step argument as well as a start and a stop.

For example:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: np.arange(10)
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [3]: x = np.arange(10)

In [4]: x[::2]
Out[4]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])

In [5]: x[::3]
Out[5]: array([0, 3, 6, 9])

In [6]: x[3::3]
Out[6]: array([3, 6, 9])
```

If you're asking how to find even multiples, you can use boolean indexing.

For example:

```
In [7]: x[x % 3 == 0]
Out[7]: array([0, 3, 6, 9])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000,10000,11000,12000])
>>> y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
>>> idxs = np.where(x % 3 == 0)
>>> x[idxs]
array([ 3000,  6000,  9000, 12000])
>>> y[idxs]
array([ 3,  6,  9, 12])
```

---

```
>>> x[x % 3 == 0]
array([ 3000,  6000,  9000, 12000])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function that returns the qualified values. For example:

```
def filter_indices(lst, value):
    return [v for _, v in enumerate(lst) if v % value == 0]
```

Result:

```
>>> filter_indices(l, 3)
[3, 6, 9, 12]
```

Alternatively, use the `np.where` function:

```
indices = np.where(x % 3 == 0)
py.plot(x[indices], y[indices])
```